# How to deploy s3 bucket within a docker container in CDK?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am deploying a static site with AWS CDK. This works but as the site has grown, the deployments are failing due to

> No space left on device

I am looking for solutions to this problem. One suggestion I have seen is to deploy within a docker container.

How can I do this in CDK and are there any other solutions?

Comment: Where are you running the `cdk deploy` command?

Comment: on a bitbucket pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you use cdk-pipelines to manage your deployment - thats the best way forward.

But if you have to use a docker container then I have done something similar (in Jenkins).

Steps...

1. Create a 'Dockerfile' in your project, this will be your custom build environment, it should look like this...

```
FROM node:14.17.3-slim

ENV CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT=1234 \
    CDK_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-2
    

RUN npm install -g typescript
```

2. Make sure your pipeline installs any npm packages you need
3. 'Build' your project, `npx cdk synth`
4. 'Deploy' your project,`npx cdk deploy --require-approval never`

Lastly you'll need a way to authenticate with AWS so BB Pipelines and specifically the Docker container can 'talk' to cloudformation.

But like I said, cdk-pipelines is best solution, [here is good tutorial](https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/70-advanced-topics/200-pipelines.html)

Comment: Will using a CDK pipeline fix the out of memory issue?

Comment: That error "No space left on device", is specific to your build environment, so by changing the build environment you completely remove the "problem". 

Coding a proof-of-concept (including learning time) should take you a few hours so it's worth your time trying out cdk-pipelines.

How big is the deployment bundle? Is it zipped?